# Using properties on union types

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following code I'm trying to understand how to work with union and generic types by re-implementing something similar to `Either` or `Option`.

```
type Error = {
  readonly _tag: 'error';
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
};

type Success<T> = {
  readonly _tag: 'success';
  response: T;
};

type PossibleError<T> = Error | Success<T>;

const isSuccessful = <T>(p: PossibleError<T>) => p._tag === 'success';

function fold<T>(
  onSuccess: (e: Success<T>) => void,
  onError: (a: Error) => void
): (pe: PossibleError<T>) => void {
  return pe => (isSuccessful(pe) ? onSuccess(pe.response) : onError(pe));
}
```

But I get the following error

```
error TS2339: Property 'response' does not exist on type 'PossibleError<T>'.
  Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Error'.

   return pe => (isSuccessful(pe) ? onSuccess(pe.response) : onError(pe));
                                                   ~~~~~~~~
error TS2345: Argument of type 'PossibleError<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error'.
  Type 'Success<T>' is missing the following properties from type 'Error': status, statusText

   return pe => (isSuccessful(pe) ? onSuccess(pe.response) : onError(pe));
```

I think typescript is unable to work out the type of `pe` based on my `isSuccessful` function. How do I get the right parts of my data structure to be able to do something with them?

I looked at tthe `fp-ts` [implementation](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Either.ts#L276) of either and they are able to access `.left` and `.right`, so I'm nott sure whatt is different in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close! There are two problems:

1. You need `p is Success<T>` on your [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

   ```
    const isSuccessful = <T>(p: PossibleError<T>): p is Success<T> => p._tag === 'success';
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. You're trying to pass `pe.response`, not `pe`, into `onSuccess`, but `onSuccess` is defined to take a `Success<T>`, not a `T`. You need to either change the type of `onSuccess`:

   ```
    function fold<T>(
      onSuccess: (e: T) => void,
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
      onError: (a: XError) => void
    ): (pe: PossibleError<T>) => void {
      return pe => (isSuccessful(pe) ? onSuccess(pe.response) : onError(pe));
    }
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgogJwQewVAvFA3gWAFBRQIQCGAJsgHYA2IUA%20sCQOYBcUA5BEqhwNz5CAZybAArkPaUxAWwBG3AQSgiS4oQBUIAD2DsRCAJaVmSgL5L8oSFADKYgMYOIQoQB4NAPgzZBRUhQ0dIws7BxCjs6u-H7EQmBUQhDsGuaWeNbQAArIroZy1BCIKAge3pjwPGgAPnaRLu5e6Q6JwFCGQvZODQBmYtQ%20ZQAUYOw5eQVFVWUAlOxg7UJ13a5lGN5gAHQhzBjomOH10el9lA7AhlRQPcjUZMN%20hFRdUZJQQ8lQGjPrUABuyEMZAANI8oFRiqh2EMSOxKiUfuhvACgfg5u9IGNckJ8oVIaUvIjkYCyL5lIRiOIEJQoDYke8Oi9ev0RhAfgB%20cGUJmuVmbOIJShJH7sCFVVkzGbmfBAA)

   ...or pass it `pe`:

   ```
    function fold<T>(
      onSuccess: (e: Success<T>) => void,
      onError: (a: XError) => void
    ): (pe: PossibleError<T>) => void {
      return pe => (isSuccessful(pe) ? onSuccess(pe) : onError(pe));
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
    }
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgogJwQewVAvFA3gWAFBRQIQCGAJsgHYA2IUA%20sCQOYBcUA5BEqhwNz5CAZybAArkPaUxAWwBG3AQSgiS4oQBUIAD2DsRCAJaVmSgL5L8oSFADKYgMYOIQoQB4NAPgzZBRUhQ0dIws7BxCjs6u-H7EQmBUQhDsGuaWeNbQAArIroZy1BCIKAge3pjwPGgAPnaRLu5e6Q6JwFCGQvZODQBmYtQ%20ZQAUYOw5eQVFVWUAlOxg7UJ13a5lGN5gAHQhzBjomOH10el9lA7AhlRQPcjUZMN%20VF1RklBDycsvs%20tQAG7IhjIABpHpRiqh2EMSOxKiUZj9-oD8HM3pAxrkhPlCuDSl54ehvIiyL5lMRxAhKFAbAS3h1nr1%20iMIPCAPxQJ5HIRM%20HsKg47kzcxAA)

---

Side note: In those, I've changed `Error` to `XError` so it doesn't conflict with the standard `Error` function.